# randomizing audio for buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I have 9 sounds for each soundpack. 
They are named: testpack1.mp3, testpack2.mp3 and so on.
I also have up to 9 Buttons. Sometimes there are just 4, sometimes 9.

I generate my Buttons and initialize the sounds with the following code:

```
-(id) initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame andPosition: (NSInteger)pos andValue: (NSInteger)value {

NSString * strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testpack%ld", (long) (value+1)];
NSString * strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strName ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL * urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath];
self.audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlPath error:NULL];
}
```

I call this method in my VC with

```
Sounds *so = [[Sounds alloc] initWithFrame:frame andPosition:i andValue:value];
```

for every single Button. 
So, value increases everytime by 1.

Ok, now the sounds will be played by pressing the generated buttons. For example, I have generated 4 buttons, this 4 buttons play every time only testpack1-4.mp3 But I want that my player takes random out of the 9 sounds.

If i just say, arc4random, and change the first line in

```
NSString * strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testpack%ld", (long) (value+randomNumber)];
```

i get sometimes nil, because its going over 9.

If i have all 9 Buttons, all Sounds have a specific button. everything is fine. i i have just 4  or 6 buttons, my player always take only the first 4 or 6 sounds, but never 6 out of the 9.

I hope my questions is understandable, i don't know how to explain my problem better...

Answer (score 0):

Just generate a random number between 0 to 9 using

```
NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 10;
```

I think in your case, use `arc4random() % 9` and add one while creating a string so that it can never be 0 or above 9

Comment: That won't work. Because my value increases every time by 1. So I get out of the area 1-9. Ar the first call of the method value is 0, so the sound is 1. Second time the value is 1, so the sound is 2 and so on...